# Is there a way to initialize a public array based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have an array with 3 dimensions. I would like to access this array from several modules in Excel VBA. For that reason I use Public to declare it. Currently I use this code:

```
Public MyData(1 To 400, 1 To 10, 1 To 3000) As Double
```

I would like to initialize the first and third variable once at startup of my code at a certain value depending on the sizes of my data.

Since ReDim can only be used for the last variable in an array I am trying to do something like this although this is not possible:

```
If x < 400 and z < 3000 Then    
    Public MyData(1 To 400, 1 To 10, 1 To 3000) As Double 
End If

If x < 200 and z < 1000 Then    
    Public MyData(1 To 200, 1 To 10, 1 To 1000) As Double 
End If
```

Is there a way to initialize an array based on a condition (the value of x and z below a certain level)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `ReDim` can be done for any dimension. `ReDim Preserve` is restricted to modify only the last dimension, keeping the existing loaded items value. But also for `ReDim Preserve` a workaround exists: You make the last dimension the one you want to redim preserve and finally transpose the array;
2. `ReDim` can be done only for a declared array but, **without dimensions setting during its declaration**. So, declaring it in the next way:

```
Public MyData() As Double
```

will work as you need...

3. A `Public` variable can only be placed on top of your module, in the declarations area. So, no any such code is allowed there. You can only `ReDim` it as you tried, in a module `Sub/Function`, only if you declare it as I recommended above

Comment: Thanks for spotting this error. So I can only ReDim once? (Which will be enough.)

Comment: @ FaneDuru It seems to me it is possible to ReDim an array twice. I have added an example above. Or do you mean something else? I see, I have lost the data in MyArray(2,9)!

Comment: @user2165379:  Yes. If you declare it without any dimensions, it is possible... I was not enough atentive when I answered in the above comment. It is good to not make exces of`ReDim`, for good memory management.

Comment: @ FaneDuru So it is not a good idea to use Redim Preserve for every increase of z due to memory management? Would it be better to increase z with steps of 1000?

Comment: @user2165379: If you are not able to estimate the maximum elements to be loaded number, and finally use `Redim Preserve` only once, solution of using big steps is better then using it for each necessary element to be loaded, yes.

Comment: Really helpful overview :-! - Addendum: it might be worth mentioning that in some cases and due to MS help reference "the ReDim statement acts as a **declarative statement** if the variable it declares doesn't exist at the module level or procedure level. If another variable with the same name is created later, even in a wider scope, ReDim will refer to the later variable and won't necessarily cause a compilation error, even if Option Explicit is in effect. To avoid such conflicts, ReDim should *not* be used as a declarative statement, but simply for redimensioning arrays." @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical `ReDim` example:

```
Public multiArray()

Sub initL()
    Dim larry As Long, moe As Long, curley As Long
    
    larry = 7
    moe = 11
    curley = 13
    
    ReDim multiArray(1 To larry, 1 To moe, 1 To curley)
End Sub
```